# Salesforce apex controller extension for custom object and visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have 2 custom objects i have created and due to the limitations of salesforce lists and reports i cant get more then 255 characters to be displayed on a long textarea.

```
Sales_Trip__c
- Name - string
- Date_From - date
- Date_To - date
- Salesman - lookup User


Sales_Trip_Visit__c
- Sales_Trip - master-detail
- Account - master-detail
- Notes - Long Textarea
- Date - date
```

so i'm trying to create a new visualforce page that displays the sales_trip_visit__c's in a table ordered by Sales_Trip_Visit__c.Date

I have the page working using the Sales_Trip__c standard controller
But that returns the visits unordered.

From what i can tell i cant do that within the page so i am attempting to create an extension for the Sales_Trip__c standard controller that has a method that returns a list of visits ordered by the date.

This is what i have so far and i think i'm not doing something right.

```
public class mySalesTripControllerExtension {

private final Sales_Trip__c satr;

public mySalesTripControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.satr = (Sales_Trip__c)stdController.getRecord();
}

public List<Sales_Trip_Visits__c> getVisitList() {
    con = new List<Sales_Trip_Visits__c>();
    con = [SELECT Date, Account.Name, Notes FROM Sales_Trip_Visits__c WHERE Sales_Trip__c.id = :this.satr.id ORDER BY Date]
    return con;
}
}
```

I'm getting the following error but i think I am doing it completely wrong.

```
    Error: Compile Error: sObject type 'Sales_Trip_Visits__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 18 column 15
```

Thanks for the help this is now my revised code. and i have kept the nameing convention i am using which is a duplicate custom object same fields / same relationships just a different name ( original had a rich textarea. _2 has a long textarea

```
public class mySalesTripControllerExtension {

    private final Sales_Trip__c satr;

    // The extension constructor initializes the private member
    // variable acct by using the getRecord method from the standard
    // controller.
    public mySalesTripControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.satr = (Sales_Trip__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public List<Sales_Trip_Visit_2__c> getVisitList() {
        Sales_Trip_Visit_2__c con = [SELECT Date__c, Account__r.Name, Notes__c FROM Sales_Trip_Visit_2__c WHERE  Sales_Trip__r.Id = :satr.id ORDER BY Date__c];
        return con;
    }
}
```

Current error.

```
Error: Compile Error: Return value must be of type: LIST<Sales_Trip_Visit_2__c> at line 16 column 9
```

Comment: You need to prepend a variable in SOQL by : character like this
WHERE Sales_Trip__c.id = :this.satr.id

Comment: Thanks for that i now get the following error

Comment: Hmmm.. you surely forgot to past the error

Comment: i edited the error on the question with the new error.
Error: Compile Error: sObject type 'Sales_Trip_Visits_2__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 18 column 15

Comment: I know i can get the visits with Sales_Trip__c.Sales_Trip_Visit__r

but there is no way to sort the returned list is there.

Comment: In Sales_Trip_Visits_2__c Where the 2 comes from ? seems it should be Sales_Trip_Visits__c

Comment: your right it is sorry the _2 shouldnt be there.

i have 2 objects Sales_Trip_Visit__c and Sales_Trip_Visit_2__c
i was stuffing around between the 2 custom objects. i get the same error for weather i'm using Sales_Trip_visits or _2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34200/discussion-between-user966936-and-moti-korets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can make a sorting on a page but you will have to use some javascript for it. A better approach would be as you're doing to make the sorting on the controller side. 
You making it right overall except the error i mentioned in a comment.
Here is modified code

```
public List<Sales_Trip_Visits__c> getVisitList() {
   Sales_Trip_Visits__c con = [SELECT Date__c, Account__r.Name, Notes__c FROM Sales_Trip_Visits__c WHERE  Id = :satr.id ORDER BY Date__c]
   return con;
}
```

Comment: Error: Compile Error: sObject type 'Sales_Trip_Visits_2__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 18 column 15

Comment: I get the following error now. that seems to have helped a lot thanks.

your code doesnt appear to be returning a list is that because its finding no results and returning null or its failing ?

Error: Compile Error: Return value must be of type: LIST<Sales_Trip_Visit_2__c> at line 16 column 9

Comment: Ok i worked it out. had to change Sales_Trip_Visits__c to List<Sales_Trip_Visits__c>

public List<Sales_Trip_Visits__c> getVisitList() {
   List<Sales_Trip_Visits__c> con = [SELECT Date__c, Account__r.Name, Notes__c FROM Sales_Trip_Visits__c WHERE  Id = :satr.id ORDER BY Date__c]
   return con;
}